# How to cluster a large dataset based on similarity?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, dbscan

I would like to cluster a huge dataset into clusters based on similarity. How can I approach this problem? I have tried MinBatchK means and DBSCAN but I am not getting great results. The problem I am facing with MinBatchKMeans is I have to specify the number of clusters beforehand and with DBSCAN most are classified as Noise. Can someone please guide me on how to approach this problem? I am using TFIDF to convert text into vectors

For eg : When i am using a dataset of 80000 records it takes around 2-3 hours to form a cluster of size 500. This makes it very difficult to find optimal number of clusters with MinBatchK  K means as i have to change values of K and then find out optimal number with approaches as Elbow Method. Can someone who has experience please let me know how to approach this problem ?

Comment: I am new to machine learning. This is the task assigned to me. So i am starting directly with Unsupervised Learning.

Answer (score 4):

The problem of clustering large datasets without knowing the number of clusters is something really hard to tackle, as pinpointed by the [scikit-learn algorithm cheat-sheet](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html). But some workaround exist which are dataset dependent, if you can provide some a priori on your data.

1. Is your data relatively stationary – that is, if you randomly select a subset of your data, will it have approximately the same properties that the full dataset?
2. Do you expect a large cluster imbalance, e.g. do you expect a large variability of cluster population sizes?
3. Do you have a rough idea or intuition on the number of categories (even an overestimate)?

(*In the following lines, I illustrate my point with the `scikit-learn` Python library syntax, but the statements are general and can be adapted to most of machine-learning libraries.*) Depending on your answers to the above questions, you can try to apply the clustering on a subset of your data with `model.fit(x_subset)` in order to reduce the computation time, and then predict on the full dataset categories with `model.predict(x_full)`. If the data is stationary, the class inference made on the subset will have a chance to work on the full dataset. If the cluster sizes vary a lot, you may need to go with hierarchical clustering (for instance with [scipy hierarchical tools](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html)). This last tool may also be a good way to estimate the number of categories before going further with DBSCAN or any other strategy.

In any case, you are facing a problem often met in unsupervised machine learning. Note that you are trying to have an exploratory strategy (which is good), and if  no exact solution emerges for your dataset, you will always learn something from your data by extracting intermediate-level information (like the answers to the three questions above) that can drive you in the next steps to cluster the full data.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one of the effective ways dealing with large datasets is preliminary make a dimensionality reduction, i.e. PCA (Principle component analysis). Good examples could be found here: [PCA in ML](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-principal-component-analysispca/)

After apllying PCA clusters methods usually works much faster.

Comment: The problem is about the size of the population, not the number of parameters